# python pandas: list of integers as individual values of DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas

**Question:**
How to 'pd.read_csv' so that the values in a given column are of **type list** (a list **in each row of a column**)?

When creating a DataFrame (from a dict, see below), individual values are of type list. The problem: After writing the DataFrame to a file and reading from the file back to a DataFrame, I get a string instead of a list.

creating the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
dict2df = {"euNOG": ["ENOG410IF52", "KOG2956", "KOG1997"], 
           "neg": [[58], [1332, 753, 716, 782], [187]], 
           "pos": [[96], [659, 661, 705, 1228], [1414]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict2df)
```

## value is a list

```
type(df.loc[0, 'neg']) == list # --> True
type(df.loc[0, 'neg']) == str # --> False
df.loc[1, 'neg'][-1] == 782 # --> True
```

write to file

```
df.to_csv('DataFrame.txt', sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
```

read from file

```
df = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.txt', sep='\t')
```

## value is a string not a list

```
type(df.loc[0, 'neg']) == list # --> False
type(df.loc[0, 'neg']) == str # --> True
df.loc[1, 'neg'][-1] == 782 # --> False
```

Of course, it's possible to convert between the two data types, but it's computationally expensive and needs extra work (see below)

```
def convert_StringList2ListOfInt(string2convert):
    return [int(ele) for ele in string2convert[1:-1].split(',')]

def DataFrame_StringOfInts2ListOfInts(df, cols2convert_list):
    for column in cols2convert_list:
        column_temp = column + "_temp"
        df[column_temp] = df[column].apply(convert_StringList2ListOfInt, 1)
        df[column] = df[column_temp]
        df = df.drop(column_temp, axis=1)
    return df
df = DataFrame_StringOfInts2ListOfInts(df, ['neg', 'pos'])
```

**What would be a better (more pythonic) solution?** It would be very convenient to iterate over the Integers in the list without having to convert them back and forth.
Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the strings to lists.

A simple example of `ast.literal_eval()` -

```
>>> import ast
>>> l = ast.literal_eval('[10,20,30]')
>>> type(l)
<class 'list'>
```

For your case, you can pass it to `Series.apply` , so that each element in the series is evaluated (safely). Example -

```
df = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.txt', sep='\t')
import ast
df['neg_list'] = df['neg'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.drop('neg',axis=1)
df['pos_list'] = df['pos'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.drop('pos',axis=1)
```

Demo -

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: dict2df = {"euNOG": ["ENOG410IF52", "KOG2956", "KOG1997"],
   ....:            "neg": [[58], [1332, 753, 716, 782], [187]],
   ....:            "pos": [[96], [659, 661, 705, 1228], [1414]]}

In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict2df)

In [18]: df.to_csv('DataFrame.txt', sep='\t', header=True, index=False)

In [19]: newdf = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.txt', sep='\t')

In [20]: newdf['neg']
Out[20]:
0                     [58]
1    [1332, 753, 716, 782]
2                    [187]
Name: neg, dtype: object

In [21]: newdf['neg'][0]
Out[21]: '[58]'

In [22]: import ast

In [23]: newdf['neg_list'] = newdf['neg'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

In [24]: newdf = newdf.drop('neg',axis=1)

In [25]: newdf['pos_list'] = newdf['pos'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

In [26]: newdf = newdf.drop('pos',axis=1)

In [27]: newdf
Out[27]:
         euNOG               neg_list               pos_list
0  ENOG410IF52                   [58]                   [96]
1      KOG2956  [1332, 753, 716, 782]  [659, 661, 705, 1228]
2      KOG1997                  [187]                 [1414]

In [28]: newdf['neg_list'][0]
Out[28]: [58]
```

Comment: thank you! this is more pythonic in the sense that it uses a library instead of my own code. I was hoping to find a solution that would include this conversion when reading the data frame.