# Python Pandas: convert list of objects to a list of integer

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a prboblem to **convert list of objects to a list of integers**. The objects are within the "stopsequence" column of the Pandas data frame "Kanten". All of this I receive after so CSV importing and data cleaning in the column. I am using Python 3.X

I am a Python newbie, maybe that's part of the problem here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import ast
orgn_csv = pd.read_csv(r"Placeholder path for csv file")
df = orgn_csv.dropna()
Kanten = pd.DataFrame({"stopsequence" : df.stopsequence})

# In between is a block in which I use regular expressions for data cleaning purposes.
# I left the data cleaning block out to make the post shorter


Kanten.stopsequence = Kanten.stopsequence.str.split (',')
print (Kanten.head())
print (Kanten.stopsequence.dtype)
```

This gives the following output:

```
                                        stopsequence
2  [67, 945, 123, 122, 996, 995, 80, 81, 184, 990...
3  [67, 945, 123, 122, 996, 995, 80, 81, 184, 990...
4  [67, 945, 123, 122, 996, 995, 80, 81, 184, 990...
5  [67, 945, 123, 122, 996, 995, 80, 81, 184, 990...
6  [67, 945, 123, 122, 996, 995, 80, 81, 184, 990...
object
```

I am looking for a way to transform the list which contains objects. I searched through the StackOverflow Forum intensively and tried a bunch of different approaches. With none of them I was succesfull.
I tryed to use:

[astype(str).astype(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

```
Kanten.stopsequence = Kanten.stopsequence.astype(str).astype(int)
This Returns:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

adapted the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float) with the use of atoi instead of atof

```
Kanten.stopsequence.applymap(atoi)
This Returns:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'
```

[list(map())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

```
Kanten.stopsequence = list(map(int, Kanten.stopsequence))
This returns:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

[apply(ast.literal_eval)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399989/python-pandas-list-of-integers-as-individual-values-of-dataframe)

```
Kanten.stopsequence = Kanten.stopsequence.apply(ast.literal_eval)
This returns:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Does anybody see a solution for that? I am uncertain if it's a complicated case or I just lacke some further programming experience. If possible a short explanation would be helpful. That I can find a solution myself againg. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A sample of `stopsequence`?

Comment: You say you import this data from a CSV file. Why are you not creating the ```DataFrame``` directly from the CSV?

Comment: @DirtyBit Do you mean a sample of the original values which I loaded in from the CSV file?

Comment: @emporerblk I added the `read_csv` as well to make it more clear what I am doing.
I am kind of learning while I am doing it. So it is definitely possible that I am doing things which are not 'ideal'.

Answer (score 0):

A pandas `Series` can be trivially converted to a list, and a list of lists can be given as input to create a `DataFrame`.

I think this could help:

```
splitted = pd.DataFrame(Kanten.stopsequence.str.split (','), index=Kanten.index).astype(int)
```

This gives you a new dataframe with same index as the original one but where each element is in its own column.

If relevant, you could then concat that new columns

```
pd.concat([Kanten, splitted], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your second attempt at manipulating the data, your error message tells you that `Kanten.stopsequence` is a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), not a `DataFrame`. To convert, you'd need to access

```
list_of_lists = Kanten.stopsequence.to_numpy(dtype='int32').tolist()
```

Note that for your data this will create a nested 2d data array. To access the first integer from the first row, you would need to write `list_of_lists[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach pulling the last column of a DataFrame into a list of ints.

Let's say the `.csv` is located in the same directory as your `.py` script and it's called `kanten.csv`. The column you're looking for is `stopsequence`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path=os.getcwd()
filename = 'kanten.csv'
filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)

kanten = pd.read_csv(filepath)
list = list(kanten['stopsequence'].apply(lambda x: int(x)))
```

In the last line, the `stopsequence` column is pulled from `kanten`, the values are casted as integers, then the column is converted to a standard python list object.